Fastlane to generate xcarchive from a Maui project
I have a .net Maui app that I'm trying to publish. Apple requires an xcarchive for the app to be uploaded but VS for Mac won't generate one anymore. It used to be generated when we used Xamarin but that has now been deprecated. Maui will successfully generate an ipa file but Apple won't accept that for upload. They want the xcarchive I'm not certain how to use Fastlane to generate the xcarchive without an xcodeproj file, which Maui also doesn't generate. That's the reason the fastlane code below doesn't work.
  build_app(
    configuration: "Release",
    project: "Path/To/My.xcodeproj",
    export_method: "app-store",
    export_options: {iCloudContainerEnvironment: "Production"},
    skip_codesigning: true,
    skip_package_ipa: true,
    archive_path: "MyArchiveName.xcarchive"
 )

dotnet build commands that rely on the xcodeproj don't work either. Any thoughts?
